# Was the first use of glass teleprompters in Lyndon Johnson’s speech to the UN’s 20th anniversary celebration? (1965)

Tags: united-states, president, united-nations

I came across a short video recording of his speech at *[c-span.org](https://www.c-span.org/video/?14775-1/un-history-newsreel)*

I was surprised by the appearance of the sleek glass devices that appear to be teleprompters beside the podium. They appear almost identical with the modern versions.

Is this the first recorded use of glass teleprompters?

It’s ambiguous but I think references to a ‘glass teleprompter’ refers to a system as seen in [this photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprompter#/media/File:LBJ_Civil_Rights_Act_crowd.jpg). similar to the TV camera ones currently in use, but unlike the speech style ones.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on Teleprompter history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprompter#History) doesn't say who used it publicly first, but it does mention several previous politicians using it, including speakers at both the Republican and Democratic conventions in 1952.

Comment: @justCal It’s ambiguous but I think those references to a ‘glass teleprompter’ refers to a system as seen in this photo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprompter#/media/File:LBJ_Civil_Rights_Act_crowd.jpg. Similar to the TV camera ones currently in use, but unlike the speech style ones.